# Click on checkbox is not checking checkbox instantly

Tags: reactjs, react-table

when I click in the checkbox of the table row, I am updating the array selecteddata with id and after that I am passing the checked value by finding whether id exists in the selecteddata to check the checkbox. I am able to store the id in selectedData but it is not showing instance changes in checkbox.

```
const [selectedData, setSeletcedData] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckboxSelect = (id) => {
    setHasSelectedAll(false);
    setSeletcedData((selectedData) => {
      if (selectedData.includes(id)) {
        return selectedData.filter((currentId) => id !== currentId);
      } else {
        selectedData.push(id);
        return selectedData;
      }
    });
  };



<CDataTable
          items={matter}
          fields={fields}
          hover
          pagination
            count: (item) => (
              <CFormGroup variant="checkbox" className="checkbox">
                <CInputCheckbox
                  id="checkbox1"
                  name="checkbox1"
                  value="option1"
                  checked={selectedData.includes(item.id)}
                  onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxSelect(item.id)}
                />
              </CFormGroup>
            ),
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning the same array reference in the line

```
selectedData.push(id);
return selectedData;
```

which won't cause the component to re-render, you should return a new array with the new item with, using `spread operator`  or `Array Cloning`

`spread operator` :

```
     return [...selectedData,id];
```

`Cloning` :

```
     const newArray = Array.from(selectedData);
     newArray.push(id);
     return newArray;
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, i am new to react so such issues are always bugging me

Answer (score 1):

Use `spread operator` to return new Array instead `push`

```
else {
  return [...selectedData, id];
}
```

Comment: i think you are mean to spread selectedData not id

Comment: should be [...selectedData,id]